# Mysql Rank based on Avg

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these columns

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|id | deviceId | totalMethaneInGrams | totalFeedInMinutes | date      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |141       | 402                 |305                 |2020-10-13 | 
|2  |141       | 410                 |368                 |2020-10-13 | 
|3  |145       | 361                 |300                 |2020-10-13 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now i want to calculate an average of  *totalMethaneInGrams* and *totalFeedInMinutes* for a subset of devices. where date is less than some day. Group them by devicedId, order them by `avg(totalMethaneInGrams)` and get a global rank of those devices based on `avg(totalMethaneInGrams)`.

This what i have up until now,

```
SELECT
    deviceId,
    ROUND(avg(totalFeedInMinutes),2) as methane,
    ROUND(avg(totalMethaneInGrams)) as feed
FROM sensor_data 
WHERE
    deviceId IN (141,123,145) AND date < '2020-10-14' 
GROUP BY deviceId 
ORDER BY methane
```

Now what i don't understand is how to calculate global rank. My understanding is we need to calculate rank of all devices in the table. Then i can just search for the devices in the returned global dataset.  Can it be done in a single query ?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: BTW there are 3 errors in your query , square brackets [] are invalid in mysql and the date test will never return anything from sample data ad you are averaging totalFeedInMinutes twice

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  My bad those are just typos in the question. The query actually works fine. As its part of a webserver so the query is build dynamically.

The version of mysql  is 8.0.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not do rank over multiple columns well (eg feed within methane) a workaround is to do separately and join

```
SELECT  t.deviceId,
    ROUND(avg(totalMethaneInGrams),2) methane,
    rank() over (order by ROUND(avg(totalMethaneInGrams),2 ) desc) as rankmethane,
    max(feed) feed,
    max(rankfeed) rankfeed
fROM t
join
(SELECT
    deviceId,
    ROUND(avg(totalFeedInMinutes)) as feed,
     rank() over (order by ROUND(avg(totalFeedInMinutes),2 ) desc) as rankfeed
fROM t
WHERE deviceId IN (141,123,145) AND date < '2020-10-14'
group by deviceid) s
on s.deviceid = t.deviceid
WHERE t.deviceId IN (141,123,145) AND date < '2020-10-14' 
GROUP BY t.deviceId ;

+----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+
| deviceId | methane | rankmethane | feed | rankfeed |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+
|      141 |  406.00 |           1 |  337 |        2 |
|      145 |  361.00 |           2 |  400 |        1 |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```